# how do i solve a 404 error in Django for images

Tags: django, image, http-status-code-404, django-staticfiles

I am stuck on this 404 error

When I try to find what the error is using inspection I get this

[image: When I try to find what the error is using inspection I get this]

My settings code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIR =[
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

How i refer to my image in the html file

```
<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="Image">
```

My urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('amitians.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I have a static folder inside which i have an images folder

[image: I have a static folder inside which i have an images folder]

On my inspection page the file type is shown as text/html though its clearly a .png. Not sure if its related but here

[image: On my inspection page the file type is shown as text/html though its clearly a .png. Not sure if its related but here]

and my error as shown in the command prompt geos like this:

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[12/Dec/2020 13:44:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2616
[12/Dec/2020 13:44:45] "GET /static/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1772
```

I've tried many solutions on stackoverflow but cant seem to get it working
I've tried using my image file directly in the statics folder too.

Would be GLAD if someone cud help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this add and static directory in your apps and in each static directory add another directory with the app name like below:

```
├───Project_Directory
│   ├───app_name
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   ├───static
│   │   │   └───app_name
│   │   │       ├───css
│   │   │       └───images
```

now in your template use:

```html
<img src="{% static 'app_name/images/logo.png' %}" alt="Image">
```

and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using jinja format inside the global jinja format. Check to whether you have loaded static as baseUrl;

{% static "images" as baseUrl %}

Answer (score 0):

just add like this it will solve your problem :
settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIR =[
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

In your html file

```
<img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'images/background.jpg' %}>
```